# Xcode. Добавить девайс для тестирования

Tags: xcode, ios, ios7

Всем привет! Пишу приложение для iOS. Тестирую на iPod 5.  Всё нормально запускается. Как можно добавить новый девайс человека, который находится удаленно, чтобы он тоже мог его тестировать? Девайс с UDID  уже добавил в Developer Center. Но все равно, когда отсылаю человеку .ipa файл, он у него не запускается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри на сервис Testflightapp

Comment: Спасибо! Testflightapp указал на ошибку, я просто билд делал в девелопмент режиме, а надо было в дистрибьюшн (ad hoc). Кстати, удобный сервис

Answer (score 0):

Дак еще нужно сгенерироать провижен для девайса и чтоб он его скачал и установил.

Comment: создать провижн и собрать с ним приложение действительно нужно, а вот ставить на устройство, по-моему, не обязательно т.к. информация об этом устройстве уже имеется в ипашке, но не уверен

Comment: нет. провижен должен быть установлен. Он дает право работать с ad-hok приложением. Без провижена приложение будет пытаться установиться, но не сможет.

Comment: достаточно ipa файла, который подписан prov prfile'ом, в который включен соответствующий udid девайса. все ставится через тунец, например, и работает без проблем.

Comment: Блин ок, спасибо за настойчивость. проверю.

Comment: Ребят, я не нашел как можно провиженом подписать, я понимаю подписать сертификатом, но как провижен затолкать в ipa не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно в провижн добавить udid устройства, потом собрать с этим провижном и отправить ипашку

Comment: Да, верно. Но сам провижн еще должен был быть  в distribution mode